# Where is the QR code listed in Electrum 3.0.3

Tags: electrum

Quick question...Where can I get the QR code for Electrum 3.0.3
where is it stored? I looked at the different tabs but NO luck

Someone is trying to send me some coins and asked me for the QR code.

Where can I see this code? and are they maybe referring to the address of the wallet?

Clarity needed here, Help out please!

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are talking about the QR code for an address in your wallet. If you go to the receive tab, you will see a receiving address filled in the `Received address` text box. Next to that, there's a QR code. That QR code is for your address.